# Qt: How to access an element dragged on the main window by its id?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

I have created a `Table View` by dragging and dropping it on the main window of a Qt application. The `objectName` of this `Table View` is set to `tableView` which seems to be only defined in the `mainwindow.ui` xml file. How can I access and set some properties of `tableView` from `main.cpp` or any other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access and set the properties of tableview from the `mainwindow.cpp`(not from the `main.cpp` ). Use `ui.tableView`.(properties or function) to edit the properties you need.
May my answer can help you.

Comment: Maybe your project's name isn't `mainwindow` that the source file name will not be `mainwindow.cpp`. If that true, you can find the source file which quotes `ui_(your project name).h`